# how to check if single file is has read only attribute in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting

I was wondering if there's a way to check whether a single file has a read-only attribute using a batch script.
Something like: *if file is read-only
echo read-only!*

I've tried the following but to no avail:

```
set ATTRIBS=%%~aF
set CURR_FILE=C:\a.txt
set READ_ATTRIB=!ATTRIBS:~1,1!
if !READ_ATTRIB!==- (
    @echo !CURR_FILE! is read-write
) else (
    @echo !CURR_FILE! is read only
)
```

Thanks,
Shai.

Comment: Having the read-only attibute and being read-only are different things. What do you exactly need?

Comment: The simplest solution might be: `attrib myfile.txt | findstr "^.....R" >nul 2>nul && echo "read-only!"`

Comment: @BohdanLevchenko, `dir /ar myfile.txt >nul 2>&1 && echo read-only` will filter for read-only files without requiring a pipe or external programs such as attrib.exe or findstr.exe.

Comment: something like this: If a.txt is read-only do something....

Comment: Batch never dies. Depending on if you are allowed to touch that file, how about:
"(>nul call;>>myfile.txt) && echo I can write!" - The trick is the "call;" to generate nothing, which is tried to append it to the file.